# Calculating a trajectory using a homography projection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

I have the homography matrix and I projected a scene using that homography matrix.
Now I have trajectories in 2D, I want to transform them into the projected scene.

I'm trying to do object detection in one image, and do a homography calculations of trajectories of that image, I don't know how to convert the coordinates from the detected bounding box centers of the first image to converted homography coordinates image

```
 p = np.array(((trk[1] + trk[3]) / 2,  (trk[0] + trk[2]) / 2, 1)).reshape((3, 1))
    temp_p = H.dot(p)
    sum = np.sum(temp_p, 1)
    px = int(round(sum[0] / sum[2]))
    py = int(round(sum[1] / sum[2]))

    point_lists[trk[4]].append((px, py))
    x = [i[0] for i in point_lists[trk[4]]]
    y = [i[1] for i in point_lists[trk[4]]]
    p = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)
    y = p[1] + p[0] * np.array(x)
    fitted = list(zip(x, y))
    cv2.polylines(dst, np.int32([fitted]), False, color=(255, 0, 0))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do [this example ?](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) but in Python instead of C++??

Comment: @zipzit I'm trying to do object detection in one image, and do a homography calculations of trajectories of that image, I don't know how to convert the coordinates from the detected bounding box centers of the first image to converted homography coordinates image

Comment: You could try applying the same homographic transform to the coordinates of the bounding box. The resulting points will likely no longer form a rectangle so find a rectangle that encompasses all four points and that'll be your final bounding box.

Comment: @Jello I didn't understand your comment. Can you post an answer ? but what about the trajectory points that I'm fitting line for them... that's my interest to plot not the bounding box

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I took it as follows: you have two images with a homographic transform calculated between them. In the first image you have a bounding box around an object and you want to find that same bounding box location in the second image. Is that correct?

Comment: @jello Now I don't have two images, I just have one camera image and I have it's H matrix and I want to transform the bounding box detected in that image into the homographic image

Comment: Could you post a sample image and the bounding box coordinates?

Comment: @Jello Please find the updated post. Here is a picture with bounding box coordinates and as you see the trajectory

Comment: @Jello ou have two images with a homographic transform calculated between them. In the first image you have a bounding box around an object and you want to find that same bounding box location in the second image. Is that correct?

YES it's Correct